# ASP.net #c compare to null not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, null

```
       Artwork.ArtworkMyAvailableVotesDataTable dtCommon2 = new Artwork.ArtworkMyAvailableVotesDataTable();
        using (ArtworkTableAdapters.ArtworkMyAvailableVotesTableAdapter artworkTemplates = new ArtworkTableAdapters.ArtworkMyAvailableVotesTableAdapter())
        {
            artworkTemplates.Fill(dtCommon2, Master.loginData.loggedInUser.ID);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dtCommon2.Count; i++)
        {
            string voteStatus;
            if (dtCommon2[i].isApproved == System.DBNull.Value)
            {
```

The isApproved returns null true or false... but nothing I try seems to work to compare if it's null, it wont build.

> Error 1   Operator '==' cannot be
>   applied to operands of type 'bool' and
>   'System.DBNull'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `isApproved` is ordinary boolean.. anyway if it's `bool?` you can play it safe with such code:

```
if (dtCommon2[i].isApproved == null || !dtCommon2[i].isApproved.Value)
```

Edit: You're not using ordinary DataTable where the raw value can be indeed DBNull.. I guess the component you're using is dealing with this already and present you with "ready to use" class of data. So if `isApproved` is boolean it will already be false when the field will be empty.

Comment: Everything I try keeps throwing invalid casts etc: "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid." Fieldtype is bit if that makes any difference.

Comment: This will not work, since the issue is with trying to compare a `bool` (a value type) to `null`.

Comment: @Tom when you click F12 on the `isApproved`, what exactly do you see? What is its exact data type?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because we cannot assign Null to bool. Either you need to make IsApproved as Nullable boolean, can be achieved by declaring like bool? IsApproved. Or you need to check like dt[i] != null.

UPDATE: Try this Convert.IsDBNull(object) check whether is null or not. You can also use Convert.ToBoolean(object). It will return false, if the object is null.

Comment: How do I work out if it's returned null from the data table then?

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly states isApproved  is a bool type, not bool? or anything else. If this is the case, I suggest you to review the logic of the program. Maybe you must declare it as bool? on ArtworkMyAvailableVotesDataTable, but I'm not sure that's an option.

Comment: I think that `bool?` is being cast to `bool` automatically on certain conditions like comparing it with other types.